# how to play stream in android using videoview?Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Tags: android, video-streaming, filenotfoundexception, android-videoview

I have an issue it is not resolving long time, i am playing a stream url in android. giving error `path is null`

```
12-08 16:31:32.678: D/MediaPlayer(5386): setDataSource IOException happend : 
12-08 16:31:32.678: D/MediaPlayer(5386): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: "url"
12-08 16:31:32.678: D/MediaPlayer(5386): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

even file is present on server and run on system directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved, this error is fromnetworking side, they locked port from wifi...working it on 3G.

Comment: thnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx so much